# Getting compile error: package com.twilio.sdk does not exist

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, twilio

New-bee in java here.
I'm on an ubuntu 12.04 machine.

I am trying the Twilio API using java to make voice calls from an uiautomator test case and following the instructions provided at https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install. I downloaded  both `twilio-java-sdk-3.4.2-with-dependencies.jar` and `twilio-java-sdk-3.4.2.jar` from http://search.maven.org/#browse|1260284827 (pre-built).

I am using Twilio API in an uiautomator java project. I am able to build and run that uiautomator java project without implementing the Twilio API code. But if I try to use the Twilio API library, I get a compile time errors that it **could not find the package**.

**Steps I'm doing:**

1-> Open the java project in eclipse

2-> Add the Twilio java library `twilio-java-sdk-3.4.2-with-dependencies.jar` OR `twilio-java-sdk-3.4.2.jar` via `BuildPath->Configure Build Path->Add External JARs`.

I have following line of code to test if I can make the `TwilioRestClient` object. I have other test functions with the uiautomator and they work fine without this piece of code. Consider the following method in addition to other test methods.

**test.java**

```
//Assume all other required libraries are imported
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;

public class testClient extends UiAutomatorTestCase {   

    public void testMethodGetClient(){
        try{
            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("ACCOUNT_SID", "AUTH_TOKEN");
            log.info("client: " + client.getAccountSid());
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.info(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I do not get any reference errors in my code before the `comiple/build` command. To believe that, if I do `client.` ,eclipse shows me all the methods available for the `client` object. So, can I assume here that my import was successful?
Then I go the terminal and execute below command to create the `build.xml` file:

**ubuntu terminal**

```
$> android create uitest-project -n JARNAME -t 1 -p <PATH-TO-PROJECT>
$> ant clean build
Buildfile: <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at <ANDROID-SDK-PATH>

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/bin

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at <ANDROID-SDK-PATH>

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for <PACKAGE-NAME>...
[getuitarget] Project Target:   Android 4.2.2
[getuitarget] API level:        17
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /<PATH-TO-PROJECT>/bin/classes

-pre-compile:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 33 source files to <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/bin/classes
    [javac] <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/test.java:15: package com.twilio.sdk does not exist
    [javac] import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
    [javac]                      ^
[javac] <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/test.java:42: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class TwilioRestClient
[javac] location: class <packagename>.Telephony
[javac]             TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("ACCOUNT_SID", "AUTH_TOKEN");
[javac]             ^
[javac] <PATH-TO-PROJECT>/test.java:42: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class TwilioRestClient
[javac] location: class <packagename>.Telephony
[javac]             TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("ACCOUNT_SID", "AUTH_TOKEN");
[javac]                                           ^
    [javac] 3 errors

BUILD FAILED
<ANDROID-SDK-PATH>/tools/ant/uibuild.xml:183: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

The above command would create the .jar if I did not have the testMethodGetClient method. So, I serached for the articals for `package not found` errors, but most of them suggesting to add the library either via 'Add External Jars' or 'provide the class path'. I tried both and I get the same error. So, I came here and posting it as a new question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bgossit's answer did help me going to the right direction. However, that alone was not enough. So, answering my question by my self explaining a little extra step I had to do.

My first bottle neck is resolved, that is to compile the project successfully. However, I am still not able to run the project on an Android device. I am marking this comment as an answer as the question was for the complie error. I am puting a new question for the runtime error.

I found that the uiautomator's '`android create project`' command creates a '`build.xml`' which internally calls '`<ANDROID_SDK>/sdk/tools/ant/uibuild.xml`' to build the project and create the final jar. By default, the '`compile`' target in this '`uibuild.xml`' does not have a '`classpath`' inlcuded for the jar. This seems to be the bug with Android as mentioned on couple of other StackOverflow questions/answers.

**Solution that worked for me:**

1. Create the '`libs`' directory at the same level as your '`src`' directory and put your external jars into '`libs`' directory. **Note:** This is just a good practice. Ideally you can give any name to the 'libs' directory and put it wherever you want.
2. Add the '`classpath`' attribute to the '`compile`' target in `<ANDROID_SDK>/sdk/tools/ant/uibuild.xml`.

> ```
> <classpath>
>    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}" includes="*.jar" /> <!-- path to 'libs' -->
> </classpath>
> ```

**PLEASE NOTE:** Although, above solution worked to compile and build my project, I'm still not able to run it on the Android device as the Android device would not have Twilio API jar. I am looking for the ways to build the final project jar with Twilio jar/classes. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for package com.twilio.sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692850/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-for-package-com-twilio-sdk)

Regards,

Rumit

Answer (score 2):

The default location for third party jars is normally the `libs` folder at the base of your project, i.e. `<PATH-TO-PROJECT>`.