# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for package com.twilio.sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, build

This is in continuation to my previous question: [Getting compile error: package com.twilio.sdk does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588186/getting-compile-error-package-com-twilio-sdk-does-not-exist)

I got to resolve the complie error and now trying to run the `uiautomator` test on an android device. However, I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` as the android device would not have `Twilio API` jars/classes.

So, I searched for solutions where I could build my final jar with Twilio API jar or the classes within that. I came across '`jar-jar`' and '`one-jar`' approaches to do so but did not work. I may be doing something wrong here. I'd really appreciate if someone could give a sample how to use any of these approaches.

I also found couple of other suggestions to do it via '`build.xml`' such as adding the following line to the '`-jar`' task:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
```

The above approached did include the Twilio classes to my final jar (my final jar size got increased by the size of the Twilio jar), however, my final jar could not persist the directory strucure for the Twilio classes within it. My final jar had all the classes at the root directory and all the folders were blank.

So, I am not aware of any more approaches to resolve this. If anyone of you have any suggestions/idea, please share.

Regards,

Rumit

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to crate a uber jar containing the class files in all the dependency jars. Use [ZipFileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) ant element. Please see [uber jar using ant](http://mynotes.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/uber-jar-using-ant/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Following jar files are required to run twilio properly

1. commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
2. commons-logging.jar
3. gwt-twilio-1.1.jar
4. twilio-java-sdk-3.3.14.jar
5. org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.3.1.jar

You have not provided the full stacktrace.I have done few projects in twilio and I use the above jar files otherwise `classnotfound` error occurs